# Blazor : Pass Component to RenderFragment

Tags: c#, blazor

I am trying to pass a ListItem component to a List component to be displayed.

The ListItem Component looks like this:
Razor:

```html
<li>
    @Item
</li>
```

C#

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
namespace Components
{
    public partial class TextListItem
    {
        [Parameter]
        public new string Item { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This should just show a list item with text in it.

The List Component looks like this:
Razor:

```html
@typeparam T
<ul>
        @foreach(T item in Items)
        {
                @ChildContent(item)
        }
</ul>
```

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
namespace Components
{
public partial class ListComponent<T> 
    {
        [Parameter]
        public List<T> Items { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment<T> ChildContent { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This should just fill the unordered list with list items.

And then in Index I have something like:

```html
<ListComponent Items = "@textList" >
    @context.Item
</ListComponent>
@code{
    private List<TextListItem> textList;
    protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    base.OnInitialized();

    textList = new List<TextListItem>() 
    { 
        new TextListItem(){Item ="one" },
        new TextListItem(){Item ="two" },
        new TextListItem(){Item ="three" },
    };
  }
    
}
```

I don't get back HTML from the list textList, just the text in Item.
I am making this complex because I want to get various fragment of HTML back for different types of lists.
Why don't I get the HTML back? I think I am supposed to.
Thanks!

Comment: You are only getting the text because you never actually render the `TextListItem` component. You are passing `@context.Item` to the `RenderFragment<T> ChildContent` parameter and this is only the text.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had thought of that, too. But if I pass in `@context` for example then I just get the name of object type : "Components.TextListItem". I can't figure out how to get it to render.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you actually want to do is to create a templated component, which renders the use of the TextListItem superfluous, which is, in any case is not only not used in your code, but is not possible.

This: `new TextListItem(){Item ="one" }` is not allowed in Blazor. You can't create a Razor component like that... Item is a component parameter, and you can't set it like that. Didn't you get a warning message telling you not to modify the component's state outside of the component.

Here's the code how to do that. Copy and test.

### ListComponent.razor.cs

```
public partial class ListComponent<TValue>
    {
        [Parameter]
        public List<TValue> Items { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment<TValue> ChildContent { get; set; }

    }
```

### ListComponent.razor

```
@typeparam TValue
<ul>
    @foreach (TValue item in Items)
    {
        @ChildContent(item)
    }
</ul>

@code {

}
```

### Index.razor

```
@page "/"

<ListComponent Items="@textList" Context="Item">
    <li>@Item</li>
    
</ListComponent>
@code{
   
    private List<string> textList = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It appears that it is indeed not possible then to do what I wanted without using something like @Dimitris-Maragkos. What I wanted to achieve is to create a simple List in which the ListItems take care of their own rendering. The List could contain simple text or Links or an image with text and a button and only the ListItems would need to vary. Seems not to work. Thanks.