# Blazor component: change classes based on number of children

Tags: blazor, blazor-component

I think it should be relatively simple but I could not find how to do it.

I have this:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-12-small">
        <p>
            Lorem lipsum.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-12-small">
        <span class="image fit">
            <img src="images/test.jpg"/>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I would like to create a component that would help make coding faster and cleaner.
I would like something like this:

```html
<MyGrid>
    <MyGridColumn>
        <p>
            Lorem lipsum.
        </p>
    </MyGridColumn>
    <MyGridColumn>
        <span class="image fit">
            <img src="images/test.jpg"/>
        </span>
    </MyGridColumn>
</MyGrid>
```

The component would change the classes depending on the number of GridColumn. If 2 children: "col-6 col-12-small", if three, "col-4 col-12-small",... and add maybe later more complexity.

Comment: Try `col col-12-small` you could also look at container queries a fairly new feature of html css.

Comment: @BrianParker I'm not using bootstrap, it's a custom template. The classes names don't matter here.

Comment: Make MyGridColumn register with parent using a cascading parameter and count the registrations

Comment: @Brian Parker how can I do that? Sorry, I'm really new to blazor.

Comment: does this issue help?:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73772761/blazor-pass-component-to-renderfragment

Comment: Not really but thanks. The problem here is to be able to count the number of children and adapt the classes based on that number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a registration process with the parent component. This is a basic example the registration process could exchange a lot more information, parameters, sizes etc.

`Parent.razor`

```html
<div>I have @Count children</div>
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>
```

```cs
@code {
    private List<ComponentBase> children = new();

    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; } = default!;

    internal int Count => children.Count;
    internal void Register(ComponentBase componentBase)
    {
        children.Add(componentBase);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

`Child.razor`

```cs
@ChildContent/@Parent.Count
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public Parent Parent { get; set; } = default!;

    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (Parent is null) throw new SpitTheDummyException();

        Parent.Register(this);
    }

    public class SpitTheDummyException() :
        Exception("I need a parent! Place the Child within a Parent"); // C# 12
}
```

#### Usage

```html
<Parent>
    <Child>One</Child>
    <Child>Two</Child>
    <Child>Three</Child>
</Parent>
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: What is `default!`, and can it save me from green squiggles?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 aka null forgiving you can also use `null!`. No green squiggles here :)

Comment: Okay so default, unless otherwise defined, of a class is null?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different version of Brian Parker's answer that uses the  *Blazor Component Registration* process as used in the `QuickGrid` component.

First the `Defer` component.  I'll explain what it does shortly.

```cs
@ChildContent

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

Next your `MyGridColumn`.  See the inline comments.

```cs
public class MyGridColumn : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
    [CascadingParameter] private Action<RenderFragment>? Register { get; set; }

    private bool _isRegistered;

    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        // Only do this on the first pass.
        if (!_isRegistered)
        {
            parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
            if (this.ChildContent is not null)
                this.Register?.Invoke(this.ChildContent);
        }

        // Short circuit the lifecycle stuff.
        // There's nothing for the component to render so don't waste CPU cycles doing nothing
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

`MyGrid`.  The trick here is that `Defer` is deferring the rendering of the `MyGrid` markup code in it's `ChildContent` until after the `MyGridColumn` components in `MyGrid`'s `ChildContent` has been handled by the Renderer and registered.  `Defer` is at the same level in the render tree as the `MyGridColumn`'s, and thus is handled sequentially with them.

Each `MyGridColumn` registers it's `ChildContent` render fragment delegate.  `Defer` walks through the list and renders each in turn.

I've added the column stuff and some logic to sort out the column formatting based on the number of render fragments registered.

```cs
<CascadingValue Value="Register" IsFixed>
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

<Defer>
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in _items)
        {
            <div class="@_colCss">
                @item
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</Defer>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    private List<RenderFragment> _items = new();

    private string _colCss => _items.Count switch
    {
        > 6 => "col-12 col-lg-1",
        > 4 => "col-12 col-lg-2",
        > 3 => "col-12 col-lg-3",
        > 2 => "col-12 col-lg-4",
        > 1 => "col-12 col-lg-6",
        _ => "col-12",
    };

    private void Register(RenderFragment option)
    {
        if (!_items.Contains(option))
            _items.Add(option);
    }
}
```

Finally, a demo page:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<MyGrid>
    <MyGridColumn>
        <p>
            Lorem lipsum.
        </p>
    </MyGridColumn>
    <MyGridColumn>
        <span class="image fit">
            <img src="images/test.jpg"/>
        </span>
    </MyGridColumn>
    <MyGridColumn>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Click Me</button>
    </MyGridColumn>
</MyGrid>
```

You can find more detail on the *Blazor Component Registration Pattern* here: https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.ComponentRegistration

By coincidence - I was working on the Repo today.